# Transferring Code Into A Class - Python

Tags: python, class, oop

before I post my question, I'd like to state I am still very new to Python and having trouble getting the hang of classes. I'm currently working on a program that simulates a basketball game play by play and then outputs a score. The program was going well; however, I realized that it might be best to put the code into a class to avoid future issues of the code becoming to difficult to edit. The first reason that made me come to this conclusion was that I realized that to account for overtime I would have to basically copy and paste all of my code. I realized that that would be very inefficient so decided to look for a better way to do it. I'm going to try to be as specific as possible in explaining what I'm trying to do so that you guys are able to help.

First, here's my code:

```
#Python NBA Sim Engine
#Started 6-8-2013, 10:59 PM
#Classes
import random
#Player Database
#Player = [Outside,Mid-Range,Inside,Passing,Ball Handling,Dunk,Perimeter,
#Post,Block,Steal,Speed,Strength,Height,Weight,Name]

#Miami Heat
Chris_Bosh = [67,78,87,44,41,78,34,77,81,31,60,64,'6.11',228,'Chris Bosh']
Udonis_Haslem = [24,78,81,32,39,60,44,80,59,30,57,84,'6.8',235,'Udonis Haslem']
Lebron_James = [76,72,97,97,84,97,96,88,80,88,97,90,'6.8',260,'Lebron James']
Dwayne_Wade = [66,69,90,64,78,82,80,51,42,77,89,70,'6.4',220,'Dwayne Wade']
Mario_Chalmers = [79,73,70,68,78,48,80,29,22,75,79,68,'6.2',190,'Mario Chalmers']
#San Antonio Spurs
Tim_Duncan = [31,64,94,60,33,70,30,98,80,22,33,88,'6.11',255,'Tim Duncan']
Tiago_Splitter = [4,21,75,30,17,70,39,74,60,21,35,71,'6.11',240,'Tiago Splitter']
Kawhi_Leonard = [74,75,75,66,66,84,89,52,60,78,77,60,'6.7',225,'Kawhi Leonard']
Manu_Ginobili = [80,77,80,80,75,29,64,20,11,55,70,41,'6.6',205,'Manu Ginobili']
Tony_Parker = [74,82,95,82,93,30,60,15,19,65,97,22,'6.2',185,'Tony Parker']
#Cleveland Cavaliers
Anderson_Varejao = [42,61,85,59,39,75,51,89,61,52,57,60,'6.11',240,'Anderson Varejao']
Tristan_Thompson = [20,44,80,39,32,82,44,77,77,29,59,73,'6.9',227,'Tristan Thompson']
Alonzo_Gee = [75,68,71,59,60,90,90,67,54,81,80,80,'6.6',219,'Alonzo Gee']
Dion_Waiters = [75,79,88,70,78,86,56,30,32,61,89,49,'6.4',215,'Dion Waiters']
Kyrie_Irving = [87,88,96,82,98,72,56,25,32,74,91,30,'6.3',191,'Kyrie Irving']

#Team Database
MIA = [Chris_Bosh,Udonis_Haslem,Lebron_James,Dwayne_Wade,Mario_Chalmers]
SAS = [Tim_Duncan,Tiago_Splitter,Kawhi_Leonard,Manu_Ginobili,Tony_Parker]
CLE = [Anderson_Varejao,Tristan_Thompson,Alonzo_Gee,Dion_Waiters,Kyrie_Irving]
#Engine
def engine():
    print ("1.Miami Heat\n2.San Antonio Spurs\n3.Cleveland Cavaliers")
#Variables
    Time = 2880
    FGA=0
    HTS=0
    ATS=0
#Team Names
    HTN=""
    ATN=""
#Team Variable
    HT=0
    AT=0
    HTM=input("Select home team: ")
    if HTM=="1":
        HT=MIA
        HTN="Miami"
    if HTM=="2":
        HT=SAS
        HTN="San Antonio"
    if HTM=="3":
        HT=CLE
        HTN="Cleveland"
    ATM=input("Select away team: ")
    if ATM=="1":
        AT=MIA
        ATN="Miami"
    if ATM=="2":
        AT=SAS
        ATN="San Antonio"
    if ATM=="3":
        AT=CLE
        ATN="Cleveland"
#Shooting Formula
    num1HPG=(HT[4][0])-(AT[4][6]/2)
    num2HPG=(HT[4][1])-(AT[4][6]/2)
    num3HPG=(HT[4][2])-(AT[4][6]/2)
    num1APG=(AT[4][0])-(HT[4][6]/2)
    num2APG=(AT[4][1])-(HT[4][6]/2)
    num3APG=(AT[4][2])-(HT[4][6]/2)
###
    num1HSG=(HT[3][0])-(AT[3][6]/2)
    num2HSG=(HT[3][1])-(AT[3][6]/2)
    num3HSG=(HT[3][2])-(AT[3][6]/2)
    num1ASG=(AT[3][0])-(HT[3][6]/2)
    num2ASG=(AT[3][1])-(HT[3][6]/2)
    num3ASG=(AT[3][2])-(HT[3][6]/2)
###
    num1HSF=(HT[2][0])-(AT[2][6]/2)
    num2HSF=(HT[2][1])-(AT[2][6]/2)
    num3HSF=(HT[2][2])-(AT[2][6]/2)
    num1ASF=(AT[2][0])-(HT[2][6]/2)
    num2ASF=(AT[2][1])-(HT[2][6]/2)
    num3ASF=(AT[2][2])-(HT[2][6]/2)
###
    num1HPF=(HT[1][0])-(AT[1][6]/2)
    num2HPF=(HT[1][1])-(AT[1][6]/2)
    num3HPF=(HT[1][2])-(AT[1][7]/2)
    num1APF=(AT[1][0])-(HT[1][6]/2)
    num2APF=(AT[1][1])-(HT[1][6]/2)
    num3APF=(AT[1][2])-(HT[1][7]/2)
###
    num1HC=(HT[0][0])-(AT[0][6]/2)
    num2HC=(HT[0][1])-(AT[0][6]/2)
    num3HC=(HT[0][2])-(AT[0][7]/2)
    num1AC=(AT[0][0])-(HT[0][6]/2)
    num2AC=(AT[0][1])-(HT[0][6]/2)
    num3AC=(AT[0][2])-(HT[0][7]/2)
#Calculation:
    while Time > 0:
        pos=random.randint(0,4)
        Sub = random.randint(4,24)
#Home Team
        #Center
        if pos == 0:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1HC:
                    print (HT[0][14],"hits a three!")
                    HTS = HTS + 3
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    Time = Time - Sub
                else:
                    print (HT[0][14],"misses from deep.")
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    Time = Time - Sub
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2HC:
                    print (HT[0][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[0][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3HC:
                    print (HT[0][14],"backs down",AT[0][14],"and lays it in for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[0][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Power Forward
        if pos == 1:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1HPF:
                    print (HT[1][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 3
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[1][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2HPF:
                    print (HT[1][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[1][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3HPF:
                    print (HT[1][14],"backs down",AT[1][14],"and lays it in for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[1][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Small Forward
        if pos == 2:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1HSF:
                    print (HT[2][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 3
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[2][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2HSF:
                    print (HT[2][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[2][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3HSF:
                    print (HT[2][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[2][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Shooting Guard
        if pos == 3:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1HSG:
                    print (HT[3][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 3
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[3][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2HSG:
                    print (HT[3][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[3][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3HSG:
                    print (HT[3][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (HT[3][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Point Guard
        if pos == 4:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                num=(HT[4][0])-(AT[4][6]/2)-10
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1HPG:
                    print (HT[4][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    HTS = HTS + 3
                else:
                    print (HT[4][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                num=(HT[4][1])-(AT[4][6]/2)-5
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2HPG:
                    print (HT[4][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                else:
                    print (HT[4][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3HPG:
                    print (HT[4][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    HTS = HTS + 2
                else:
                    print (HT[4][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
        pos=random.randint(0,4)
        Sub = random.randint(4,24)
        #Away Team
            #Center
        if pos == 0:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1AC:
                    print (AT[0][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 3
                else:
                    print (AT[0][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2AC:
                    print (AT[0][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[0][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3AC:
                    print (AT[0][14],"backs down",HT[0][14],"and lays it in for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[0][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Power Forward
        if pos == 1:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1APF:
                    print (AT[1][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 3
                else:
                    print (AT[1][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2APF:
                    print (AT[1][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[1][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3APF:
                    print (AT[1][14],"backs down",HT[1][14],"and lays it in for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[1][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Small Forward
        if pos == 2:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1ASF:
                    print (AT[2][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 3
                else:
                    print (AT[2][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2ASF:
                    print (AT[2][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[2][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3ASF:
                    print (AT[2][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[2][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Shooting Guard
        if pos == 3:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1ASG:
                    print (AT[3][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 3
                else:
                    print (AT[3][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2ASG:
                    print (AT[3][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                else:
                    print (AT[3][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3ASG:
                    print (AT[3][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[3][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            #Point Guard
        if pos == 4:
            sht=random.randint(1,3)
            if sht==1:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num1APG:
                    print (AT[4][14],"hits a three!")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 3
                else:
                    print (AT[4][14],"misses from deep.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==2:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num2APG:
                    print (AT[4][14],"nails the long two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[4][14],"comes up short from mid range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
            if sht==3:
                chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if chance <=num3APG:
                    print (AT[4][14],"drives to the basket and lays it for two.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
                    ATS = ATS + 2
                else:
                    print (AT[4][14],"misses from close range.")
                    Time = Time - Sub
                    FGA = FGA + 1
    else:
        if HTS > ATS:
            print (HTN,HTS,"vs",ATN,ATS)
        elif ATS > HTS:
            print (ATN,ATS,"vs",HTN,HTS)
        elif HTS == ATS:

engine()
```

The main reason I want to try and use this code as a class is to be able to account for situations like overtime. As of right now I have a "Time" variable that is subtracted from by a random amount with each possession. However, if I could somehow use a class to determine the length in "Time" that the simulation is run, I could then account for regulation as well as any overtimes and have the overtime contribute to the overall score ("HTS" and "ATS" variables).

My idea for a class would assumingly start like this:

class engine(self,time):

However, honestly from this point I feel completely lost as to where I should go next. I've been experimenting with stuff but I'm having trouble understanding how classes work beyond the very basic level and I just think this is a little over my head at this point. I realize this question may be very confusing, but I hoping someone understands it here and can at least point me in the right direction as to where I should go from here.

To list the things I'm confused about:

- I'm not sure where I should start the class. At one point I tried to break the class into to methods. One being the user interface portion and the other the actual simulation. However, I was unable to get anything close to working.
- The way variables work in classes is also confusing me. I'm not sure in what situation within a class a variable is considered global or local and this makes it very difficult to know if I will need to change where I define the HTS and ATS variables which keep track of the score.
- Aside from those two things, I'm honestly not 100% sure what I am confused about or misunderstanding as I am very new to OOP. Basically, I'm hoping someone will be able to help me move this code into a class; however, if there is something obvious you see that I am misunderstanding and you can point it out to me, that would be fine too.

Once again, I realize this may be a very confusing post so I understand if you can't help me but if anyone here understands my question(s) I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: This belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There are some very serious issues with this code that go beyond whether it's in a class. To start with one example: every *single* one of your conditionals, unless I'm mistaken, has the two lines `Time = Time - Sub` and `FGA = FGA + 1`. Why not just take those two lines outside of all of the `if` statements, and then save yourself 58 lines of code?? There are *many* other things like that that could save you literally hundreds of lines and condense this down to be readable and editable.

Comment: The FGA variable is irrelevant at this point. I honestly forgot I still had it there because I was so focused on this class thing. Before I added the time variable I had a set amount of possessions so I needed to add another Field Goal Attempt after each possession. The Time variable I still use though as time is subtracted from the Time variable after each possession. I'm not sure if you are suggesting that there is a more efficient way to remove time after a possession or if you didn't understand the variable's purpose.

Comment: I understand what you meant now. Like I stated I am very new to programming so thanks for pointing that out. I'm still hoping you can answer my question but if there is any other problems you see please point them out for me!

Comment: @Kevin02: I explain in my answer below how you could fix some of the other problems. In general this code can and should be *much* shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One *very* important rule you should learn is that *copying and pasting code is a bad idea*- especially a large amount of code, copied many times, with only very small changes each time.

The two lines that are repeated in every single `if` statement:

```
Time = Time - Sub
FGA = FGA + 1
```

are one example, but in general this code does the same logic again and again. A more illustrative example is that the *entire* code for handling the home team could be done identically using the following lines:

```
pos=random.randint(0,4)
Sub = random.randint(4,24)

chances = [[num1HC, num2HC, num3HC],
           [num1HPF, num2HPF, num3HPF],
           [num1HSF, num2HSF, num2HSF],
           [num1HSG, num2HSG, num3HSG],
           [num1HPG, num2HPG, num3HPG]]

messages = [["hits a three!", "misses from deep."]
            ["nails the long two.", "comes up short from mid range."],
            [["backs down " + AT[pos][14] + "and lays it in for two.",
              "misses from close range."]]
points = [3, 2, 2]

sht=random.randint(1,3)
chance=random.randint(1,100)

if chance <= chances[pos][sht]:
    print HT[pos][14], messages[sht][0]
    HTS = HTS + points[sht]
else:
    print HT[pos][14], messages[sht][1]
```

That's cutting the code from 180 lines to 20 lines: making it smaller by a factor of 9. Notice that it takes all the lines that are always identical, like "so-and-so hits a three!", and makes them happen only once.

That code is just a start. You might be tempted to copy and paste it again, change each use of `HT` to `AT`, and thus create the Away team logic. But don't! Instead, you could do:

```
teams = [HT, AT]
team_scores = [HTS, ATS]
```

And then replace `HT` with `teams[t]` and `HTS` with `team_scores[t]`. That way, this same logic works either for the home team or the away team: all you have to do is run it twice with different values of `t`:

```
for t in range(2):
    # all your logic here
```

Putting it in a `Team` class and `Player` classes would be an important next step, but it is *far* more important for you to start conserving your logic.

Comment: Wow! I know I'm very new to this but I definitely want to improve my coding and become more efficient. Until, I get better, I'll try and remember to plan out what I'm going to do better and avoid any copying and pasting. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Kevin02: Sure thing. You have the right instinct in being interested in classes, but as I suggest here it's most important to get these basics down first. (I would also recommend breaking your code into functions). Also note that I added an even shorter version to the answer, one that will make it especially easy to add new types of shots.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to change procedural code into OO is to model your classes based on the real-world objects. For example, in order to create a Player class:

- turn player characteristics and state into attributes
- turn player actions into methods

For example:

```
>>> class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, outside, mid_range, inside, passing, 
        ball_handling, dunk, perimeter, post, block, steal, speed, 
        strength, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.outside = outside
        self.mid_range = mid_range
        self.inside = inside
        self.passing = passing
        self.ball_handling = ball_handling
        self.dunk = dunk
        self.perimeter = perimeter
        self.post = post
        self.block = block
        self.steal = steal
        self.speed = speed
        self.strength = strength
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    def shoot(self, from_distance)
        # calculate chance here, for example...
        result = roll_dice(self, from_distance)
        if result == "scored":
            do_something()
            return
        if result == "fault":
            do_something_else()
            return
        do_default_action() # missed?

>>> chris_bosh = Player('Chris Bosh', 67, 78, 87, 44, 41, 78, 34, 
        77, 81, 31, 60, 64, 6.11, 228)
>>> print chris_bosh.height
6.11
>>> print chris_bosh.outside
67
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically it seems like I need to adjust the code to make it into a class. Thanks, for your help... I think I have better understanding of how I need to this.